# Where can I get the public keys of all popular certificate authorities

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, public-key, certificate-authority

From where I can the list of popular certificate authorities public keys .
Just like all browsers are coming with pre-installed certificates(public keys)  of certificate authorities. 
Now I am preparing ssl client which will connect to the different servers so just like browsers I need  public keys of all certificate authorities to validate the server that I am connecting.

Please at least show me the place where I can get certificate authority certificates at glance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl providers a [script](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) to extract Firefox's bundled CA certificates.